# Microsoft Word creating and editing boxes

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

In Microsoft Word 2016, I have a problem typing text in between the created box.
I have no problem creating a pentagon myself, but text cannot be added.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the steps you do to create the shapes and how you try to add text to it and what happens instead? Currently it is guessing work as to why things are not working intendedly.

Comment: I cannot understand you. Please attach and image or try to write more text so we can help you.

Comment: OK. Open word than go to insert and   to shapes, select line and arrange one after the other to make a pentagon. Than go to select object and select. now you have a pentagon which moves on the whole as a pentagon. that is you have an edited shape. A Pentagon. how try to type in between the object. It is not happening. Please help